# Searching in csv files

Tags: python, file, search, csv

How do I search between the first two commas in a csv file?
E.G:
CSV FILE:

```
    name, surname, age , gender
```

How do i only search for the first two, name and surname with the users input?

this is what i have. I am looking for the user to search only by a name or surname:

```
    searchfile = open("python.csv", "r")        
    a=input()
    for line in file: 
        if a in line:
            print(line)
```

When i do this the user can enter anything that is in the file and it will print the line. I only want to search the first two commas which are name and surname. If the input is not there then reject.

Comment: Obligatory: "What have you tried?"

Comment: Or even [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) :
it contains an object called a **reader**, which allows you to split each line of your csv file by defining a **delimiter** :

```
import csv

searchfile = open('python.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(searchfile, delimiter = ',')
a = input()
for row in reader:
    if a in row[0] or a in row[1]:
        print row
```

Note that if you're looking for a string in the csv file, you should use raw_input() instead of input() which is only used for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you could split your `line` at commas. And then search where ever you want. Something like this:

```
for line in file:             # line = "name, surname, age , gender"
    fields = line.split(',')  # fields = ["name", " surname" , " age", " gender"]
    if a in fields[0] or a in fields[1]:
        print(line)
```

Depending on your future plans, this need no to be the best solution. Also note the leading/trailing white spaces in `fields`.

Comment: this seems to print all the lines in the csv file

Answer (score 0):

use [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

```
import csv
searchfile = open("python.csv", "rb")
reader = csv.reader(searchfile)
for row in reader:
    if a in row[0] or a in row[1]:
        print row
```